# Xamarin.Forms UI Automation Testing WaitForElement WebView always times out

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

My Xamarin.Forms app uses Azure AD B2C for authentication. It works great. I'm trying to build UI automation tests now and I ran into my first blocker. I have been trying to wait for the WebView to come on the screen so I can enter the email and password of a test user into my ui test automation script however the WaitForElement method always times out!

```
[Test]
public void RegistrationStarts()
{
    app.Screenshot("Welcome screen.");

    app.WaitForElement(c => c.WebView());
    app.Tap(c => c.WebView().Css("input#logonIdentifier"));
    app.EnterText("sample@example.com");

}
```

I'm not sure why. I'm only testing in Android. I notice that the Azure AD B2C login web view appears to be inside my app. I can tell this because when I open the Android task switcher I can see Chrome and my app.

[image: screenshot of the AzureAD B2C webview]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you used input before the id? If logonIdentifier is your ID of whatever you want to type, it should just be

```
app.Tap(c => c.WebView().Css("#logonIdentifier"));
```

Also, if logonIdentifier is the TextBox in which you want to type, enter text should be

```
_app.EnterText(c => c.WebView().Css("#logonIdentifier"), "sample@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try wait for element with timeout -  time in milisecond, second, and min.

app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("AutomationID"), timeout:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));

or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.iapp.waitforelement?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `systembrowser` instead of `WebView`.

Change your method of acquiring token with WebView.

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(B2CConstants.Scopes)
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                .ExecuteAsync();
```

https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/287#issuecomment-484151924